# How do you create a new in-line item in a Vaadin Table when using JPAcontainer?

Tags: jpa, vaadin

I am using Vaadin to build a simple editor for a single database table, using JPAContainer, and a Vaadin Table component. Deleting and editing items works fine, but I am having problems adding an item.

The Vaadin tutorial explains how to add an item using a pop-up window, but I would like to add the item through the use of a new blank row in the Table. The desired functionality is to provide the user a row with some default data, and then allow the user to save the data after they are happy with the data in the new row.

The problem I am having is that I get UnsupportedOperation when attempting to do what I think should work.

My table is set up and bound to a JPAContainer for a Location entity:

```
private JPAContainer locations = JPAContainerFactory.make(Location.class,PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
```

I set the table to be buffered, so that I don't save the data to the db until the user clicks a save button:

```
    locationTable = new Table(null,locations);
    locationTable.setVisibleColumns(new Object[]{ "id","x","y","z","createDate","lastModDate"  } );
    locationTable.setSelectable(true);
    locationTable.setSizeFull();
    locationTable.setImmediate(true);
    locationTable.setBuffered(true);
    locationTable.setVisible(true);
    locationTable.setEditable(true);
```

.. a save button saves changes to the database:

```
    Button saveButton = new Button("Save Changes");
    saveButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            locations.commit();
            statusLabel.setCaption("Changes Saved");
        }
    });
```

and then I bind a button that attempts adding the new button.

```
    Button addButton = new Button("Add An Item");
    addButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

            Object newkey = locationTable.addItem(new Object[]{"NEWLOCATION","0","0","0","7/10/2013","7/10/2013"}, "NEWLOCATION");
            locationTable.select(newkey);
            statusLabel.setCaption("Item Added. Populate Data and click Save to make permanent.");
        }
    });
```

Clicking the additem button throws UnSupportedOperationException.

I have tried calling other variants of addItem, and I cannot get any to work. Does anybody know how to create a new item in a Table by using a new row in the table?

Complete init() source:

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    setContent(layout);
    final Label statusLabel = new Label("");

    locationTable = new Table(null,locations);
    locationTable.setVisibleColumns(new Object[]{ "id","x","y","z","createDate","lastModDate"  } );
    locationTable.setSelectable(true);
    locationTable.setSizeFull();
    locationTable.setImmediate(true);
    locationTable.setBuffered(true);
    locationTable.setVisible(true);
    locationTable.setEditable(true);

    Button saveButton = new Button("Save Changes");
    saveButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            locations.commit();
            statusLabel.setCaption("Changes Saved");
        }
    });

    Button addButton = new Button("Add An Item");
    addButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

            Object newkey = locationTable.addItem(new Object[]{"NEWLOCATION","0","0","0","7/10/2013","7/10/2013"}, "NEWLOCATION");
            locationTable.select(newkey);
            statusLabel.setCaption("Item Added. Populate Data and click Save to make permanent.");
        }
    });
    Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete Selected");
    deleteButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
             locations.removeItem(locationTable.getValue());
             statusLabel.setCaption("Item Removed. Click Save to make permanent.");
        }
    });


    layout.addComponent(locationTable );
    layout.addComponent(saveButton);
    layout.addComponent(addButton);
    layout.addComponent(deleteButton);
    layout.addComponent(statusLabel);



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, It is possible to do what I am after, but only with entities that have auto-generated primary keys, due to limitations in the Vaadin JPA container. 
The code i have works as expected with an autogenerated id, but fails if this is not the case.

When adding a new item to a container, com.vaadin.ui.Table delegates to its container, calling .addItem() in the case an itemId is not provided, or getItem() in the case one was provided.

For a new item, .addItem() is called:

```
/**
 * <strong>This functionality is not fully supported by this
 * implementation.</strong> The implementation tries to call empty parameter
 * constructor and add entity as such to database. If identifiers are not
 * autogenerated or empty parameter constructor does not exist, the
 * operation will fail and throw UnSupportedOperationException.
 * <p>
 * {@inheritDoc }
 */
public Object addItem() throws UnsupportedOperationException {
    try {
        T newInstance = getEntityClass().newInstance();
        Object id = addEntity(newInstance);
        return id;
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

This code explains the issue-- if the entity is cannot be created with a null contstructor in the database, this will fail.

The Vaadin examples get around this by using a Form object to gather the data, and then the addEntity() method is called, after the data is populated fully.